# Chiral Centers and Stereochemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, chirality

I was just wondering how many chiral centers this molecule has. This question might be a bit simple but I was especially confused by the bottom left "chiral center" that is bonded to a wedged ch3 and parts of a ring. Initially I thought it was a chiral center but upon further introspection it seems like two of its groups (ones next leading to ring) are exactly the same. What do you guys think about this molecule? Again I know that it is an sp3 carbon I am just confused about the terminology of its chirality. Thank you so much for your help
[image]

Comment: All chiral centers seem to be marked as it is drawn with stereo information... Therefore each carbon having a residue connected via a "triangle" is a chiral center...

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer! Would you be able to reword this more simply ? Would the bottom left carbon bonded to a methyl group count as a chiral center?

Comment: The methyl group is connected via a shim to the rest of the structure indicating that the carbon it is connected to is a chiral center. So yes the mentioned carbon is a chiral center.

Answer (score -3):

[image: how many chiral centers]

The number of chiral centres are 6.And crabon with 4 different groups is assymmetric and achiral.Hope this should help you.